# Linux on usb with virtualbox running windows 7 vhd

Tags: linux, usb, virtualbox, debian, virtual-machine

I created a USB *persistent* with **Lubuntu 16.04**, installed **Virtualbox**, an run a **Windows 7** VHD. It works ok, of course a little slow but not unusable, with machines at least 4gb of ram.

My question is, **is there a way to use a linux distribution to the bare minimum, so the VM can use the most of the hardware capacities.**

I am not a newbie in Linux, I guess I can investigate some **Debian** possibilities (I'm on it right now), but maybe the first step is asking here, someone could know better. I understand that the package dependencies is in itself a nightmare.

**QEMU** is much slower than Virtualbox, so I would eliminate as a possibility in the software stack. But maybe there are other **virtualization** software or technique (Linux) that I'm unaware of.

Thank you